# Unexpected end of file found in VS2019

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am working on simple C code
And running into an error unexpected end of file found.

I searched a lot and tried all the solutions :

1. Setting Not using precompiled headers
2. Checked for braces/parentheses
3. Checked for #endif notation
4. Checked for new line

None of this is working,

Code:

```
//test.h 
#ifndef __test_h
#define __test_h
#include <cstddef>
typedef struct
{
   // variables declared
  float a; 
   float b;
}students;

students* new();
void newfunction();
void anothernewfunction();
#endif


//test.c 
#include “test.h”   //error points here

Students*new()
{}

void newfunction()
{}

Void anothernewfunction()
{}



//testmain.c
#include ”test.h”   //error points here
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

On clicking the errors from output console, it points the cursor on #include “test.h”  in both the c files.

Output console shows only these two errors

Comment: The output console should definitely be showing more errors, e.g.: `Void` or `Students` being undeclared

Comment: The first thing you need to do is decide whether you're writing C code or C++ code. `#include <cstddef>` is only valid in C++.  But `students* new();` is definitely **not** valid in C++, because `new` is a keyword in C++.

Comment: As for the error message, it looks like you have smart quotes around `test.h`. When writing code, you need to use an editor that only uses plain ASCII text.  Smart quotes are not allowed.

Comment: @ryyker The line `students* new();` is **not** valid in C++ because it attempts to declare a function called `new`. That's not allowed in C++ because `new` is a keyword in C++. But it is allowed in C, because `new` doesn't have any special meaning in C.

Comment: @user3386109 - Head slap!  (Deleted comment. )